# Duplicate layers drawn with a UIImageView and CGAffinetransform

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, transform, cgaffinetransform

I am having an issue applying a transform to a UIImageView's layer.  Using the code below, I am trying to rotate this needle, but I am getting duplicate copies drawn.  I have checked that there is no other place where the needle image is added, and commenting out the `addSubview` makes neither one show up, so it is definitely drawing twice.

The needle on the left is in the position that the image view should be started at, `-20`.  The needle on the right works in the aspect that it rotates and displays the correct value for the `needleValue`. What am I doing wrong to get duplicate draws?

[image]

```
- (UIImageView *)needle {
 if (_needle == nil) {
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"needle.png"];
  self.needle = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];
  [_needle sizeToFit];
  [_needle setFrame:CGRectMake(floor((self.width - _needle.width)/2),
          self.height - _needle.height + 68, // this - offset comes from the lowering of the numbers on the meter
          _needle.width, _needle.height)];
  _needle.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
  _needle.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
  _needle.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

  // CALayer's transform property is a CATransform3D.
  // rotate around a vector (x, y, z) = (0, 0, 1) where positive Z points 
  // out of the device's screen.
  _needle.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.05,1);

  [self addSubview:_needle];
 }
 return _needle;
}



- (void)updateNeedle {
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; // arguments are optional
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:VU_METER_FREQUENCY];
 CGFloat radAngle = [self radianAngleForValue:needleValue];
 self.needle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radAngle);
 [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make breakpoint at the line `[self addSubview:...]` and see if it got called twice. The `_needle` variable might be set to nil somewhere else?

Comment: I feel like an idiot for not trying this earlier… I just used code inspection.